# Full disk encryption with Windows 8 and OpenSuse 13.1 on Lenovo B5400

Tags: linux, windows-8, truecrypt

I have Lenovo B5400 laptop and im trying to use full disk encryption with ability to use Linux next to Windows.

Im following [this article](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/02/23/dual-boot-fedora-18-and-windows-7-on-a-single-hdd-with-fde-on-both-ends/) but unsuccessfully because at some point truecrypt shows:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Laptop was originally without system, secure boot is turned off and hard disk has classic partition table in mbr. Is there any way to achieve full encryption or i have to stay with single system?

**Edit:**
Additional info:

Disk partitions:

```
/dev/sda1 = Windows C:\
/dev/sda2 = Windows D:\
/dev/sda3 = Linux /boot (with GRUB2)
/dev/sda4 = Linux encrypted LVM
```

MBR has windows bootloader which loads directly windows or GRUB2 to boot linux.

Truecrypt fails exactly after choosing *Number of System Drives* (page 3 in guide, 3rd image)

Answer (score 1):

I encrypted my entire drive using truecrypt while running dual boot system windows 7 + ubuntu. It should work. And it has to install a new boot loader, and will chain load the next one that asks where to boot.

Comment: Also how far into the procedure are you getting? The question about non windows bootloader seems like an easy place to make an error while dual booting with linux.

Comment: Added more info to question

Comment: /dev/sda4 = Linux encrypted LVM confuses me a little But could it be that this is encrypted so TrueCrypt doesn't recognize it properly?

Comment: So, should i install linux **after** encrypting whole disk with truecrypt?

Comment: No, once you encrypt the entire drive you will not be able to modify the system, while it is encrypted if windows breaks you will ot be able to repair it with the disc. I went away from full drive encryption when windows got corrupt from failed updates and I had to spend hours decrypting my drive from the CD before I could install windows again.